# How to installing ojdbc correctly in windows

Tags: java, oracle

I want to use network editor in oracle 11g. The network editor use for network analysis in oracle. When i try to connect to database using network editor i encounter to  an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver" . I try to install ojdbc6.jar using set classpath but i encounter same error . How can i install ojdbc and check if i install correctly this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result of dir path :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. create batch file that will set proper CLASSPATH and then start Network Data Model Editor. This is example of such batch file:

   ```
   SET CLASSPATH=c:\jars\ojdbc6.jar;c:\jars\orai18n.jar;%CLASSPATH%
   echo %CLASSPATH%
   rem here insert call to Network Data Model Editor
   pause
   ```
2. edit or create your system CLASSPATH, you will find in Computer/Properties then in Advanced tab click on "Environment Variables" and add or modify CLASSPATH. With this solution open command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and show us result of `echo %CLASSPATH%`.

**EDITED ANSWER**

In your comment I see that NetworkEditor is called via java with `-cp` option. When this option is set then `CLASSPATH` is not used.

Add CLASSPATH to batch and use it:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=...
...
SET CLASSPATH=E:\app\majid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\*;%CLASSPATH%
java ... -cp %JAR_LIBS%;%CLASSPATH% oracle.spatial.network.editor.NetworkEditor
```

You can also use it directly:

```
...
java ... -cp %JAR_LIBS%;E:\app\majid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\* oracle.spatial.network.editor.NetworkEditor
```

Comment: How can i create batch file ?  I created CLASSPATH in environment variable . but it didn't work

Comment: I added example bat file, you must insert call to Network Data Model Editor. Can you show us result of `echo %CLASSPATH%`?

Comment: The result of %CLASSPATH is the tow C:/ directories and "E:\app\majid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar"

Comment: Is this file visible in batch? Can you show result of command: `dir E:\app\majid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\o*.jar`

Comment: Niklas Thanks for your reply . I edited my question and show the result of dir ...

Comment: How do you start Network Data Model Editor? Is it batch file? Maybe it sets its own environment?

Comment: I use this code :  set ORACLE_HOME=E:\app\...\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
set JAR_LIBS=%ORACLE_HOME%/md/jlib/sdondme.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%/md/jlib/sdoapi.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%/md/jlib/sdonm.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%/md/jlib/sdoutl.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%/jdbc/lib/classes12.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%/lib/xmlparserv2.jar;
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -cp %JAR_LIBS% oracle.spatial.network.editor.NetworkEditor

Comment: Option `-cp` disables `CLASSPATH` environment variable. See my edited answer.